# DocuSign OAuth in demo mode

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

I am implementing DocuSign's OAuth flow by following their [OAuth2 doc](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html).

With demo developer account is it normal that only users specified in the Admin Dashboard are able to complete the OAuth flow?

I'm assuming so but no reference is made on the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> With demo developer account is it normal that only users specified in the Admin Dashboard are able to complete the OAuth flow?

Yes, that is normal. Perhaps you are thinking of Single Sign On (SSO). That feature uses OAuth too, and it includes dynamic account creation as needed.

The OAuth part is the same in either case. Without SSO, the users are first added via the web admin tool (or via the API). Then they can login.

If you want to use SSO, it must be set up by the DocuSign support team. Contact your sales rep to start the process.

Comment: Ok, so in demo mode users have to be added first (that makes sense), but when the app will go live will all users (already signed up in DocuSign and without a developer account ) be able to complete the OAuth flow?

Comment: Client_ids (integration keys) are account independent. So you can create an integration key on account 1 and it can be used by senders who belong to account 2. You can test this on demo: just create a new account and test that its users can use the app you created under a different account. @user3933324

Comment: In demo mode I registered another developer account and successfully completed the OAuth flow even if the user wasn't in the list of users of the OAuth app. When moving the app in live mode will all DocuSign users (even those who don't have a developer account) be able to do OAuth with it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working integration with docusign, any docusign account should probably work. I have a demo app and I'm using a live docusign account to complete the Oauth flow. But anyway, have you done some test?

Comment: I'm able to complete the OAuth flow with the account that created the OAuth app and the users invited but no one other than them.
When trying to do OAuth with a different user I get the following error message `Invalid email and / or password`.